# PHP Why can't I access this associative array value?

Tags: php, csv

I have the below code and once I pulled in a CSV file. That one key in the array had double quotes around it. I was not sure what to do so I stripped them out thinking this would allow me to simply put $array[0]['Name'] to access the string. But No! nothing. It just keeps coming up blank.

// get file and open it into a variable

```
$file = fopen('my.csv', 'r') or die('Unable to open file!');
```

// set array to return data in

```
$returnVal = array();
```

// set header variable

```
$header = null;


// loop through data
while(($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== false){
// make the header array (key)
if($header === null){
    echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($row);
    $row[0] = trim(str_replace('"', '', $row[0])); // rmove double quotes from array key
    //echo "<br>".$row[0];
     print_r($row);
    $header = $row;
    continue;
} // end of set header

//get just names and echo them 
//echo "<br>".$row[0];

// more row by row column by column and set data to correct header 
$newRow = array();

// loop rows and set data 
for($i = 0; $i<count($row); $i++){
        $newRow[$header[$i]] = $row[$i];
        //echo "<br>" . $newRow[$header[$i]];
        //$newRow['First_Name'] = $row[$i];
        //unset($returnVal['"Name"']);
}// end for loop

$returnVal[] = $newRow;

}// end while loop
```

// close csv file

```
 fclose($file);
```

// $returnVal now contains the contents of the CSV file

```
echo "Name: ".$returnVal[0]['Name'] . "<br>";
echo "Email: ".$returnVal[0]['Email Address'];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($returnVal);
// echo $returnVal[0]["Name"];

//var_dump($returnVal);
```

***************** EDIT **************************

sample output of var_dump (print_r has same output)

```
array(13500) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(10) "my name"
    ["Email Address"]=>
    string(19) "myemail@email.com"
    ["Date Added"]=>
    string(19) "2017-03-27 03:38 PM"
    ["Signup Date"]=>
    string(10) "2016-04-04"
    ["Username"]=>
    string(27) "myusername1459752576"
  }

echo "Name: ".$returnVal[0]['Name'] . "<br>"; // prints nothing
echo "Email: ".$returnVal[0]['Email Address']; // prints email just fine
```

Comment: What does that print_r prints ? It would be damn useful to know that !

Comment: And code can be condensed to http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99034fe87c8cd7ec83219f55abdd2a63663b1588

Comment: echo "Name: ".gettype($returnVal[0]['Name'])."<br>";  Echo's "NULL" if that helps. Not sure why its null when a print_r and Var_dump prints it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, it seems like

```
 reset($returnVal[0]);
```

is the answer to my issue, the reset function gave me my value for the array. But I would still like to know why the normal access to the element was not working.

Answer (score 1):

You say in a comment `rmove double quotes from array key` but you are not actually doing that. That code doesn't work. You can see in an example output of [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) that keys are not quoted, but in your sample output they are.

[`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) should remove enclosed quotes, which means either your csv files are double quoted (which may be correct) or something else is going on. You can access your property with `$returnVal[0]['"Name"']`

To actually remove keys you should probably `foreach` the header row and set `str_replace` or `trim` each key manually and set it to the $header variable. Something like this:

```
$header = array();
foreach($row as $key => $value) {
    $key = trim($key, "\" \t\n\r\0\x0B"); // trim quotes as well as standard trim characters
    $header[$key] = $value;
}
```